# Resize data partition which does not match physical storage size after installation of Android stock and Lineage

Tags: android, filesystems, partitioning, custom-rom

After an attempt to install Lineageos+Magisk on a Xiaomi Mi A1, ended in a boot loop,

1. I installed stock from `tissot_images_V10.0.9.0.PDHMIXM_20190514.0000.00_9.0_3ded3e7b82.tgz` with containing `flash_all.sh` which applies `fastboot`. I got a working starting point with a tidy a/b partitioning.
2. I flashed Lineage, addonsu and stock camera with a temporary (unflashed) TWRP

Everything works well but there is too little storage, Lineage displays a size of **32GB** instead of **64GB**

`df` tells me: `/dev/block/mmcblk0p49 19092180 15660496 3431684 83% /data`

but `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/block/mmcblk0p49` reports `55087439360` (bytes)

I mounted the userdata.img from the stock firmware mentioned above on my Linux PC and `df` showed me

`/dev/loop1 19092180 118172 18762328 1% /mnt/...`

This seems to be the source of the problem, isn't it?

(How) can I resize the partition / file system (preferably) without loosing data)?

Comment: After some investigations my current approach is

start TWRP and obtain the image 
`adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0p49 mmcblk0p49.img`

resize the file system within the image to the full extent of the partition
`e2fsck -f mmcblk0p49.img`
`resize2fs  -p mmcblk0p49.img`

and write it back
`fastboot flash userdata mmcblk0p49.img`

Are there things I you need to take into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.
TWRP has added resize2fs to its features:
https://www.theandroidsoul.com/twrp-2-8-7-0-introduces-resize2fs-feature-to-fix-incorrect-storage-space-available-on-a-device/

So I started TWRP

```
sudo fastboot boot twrp-3.3.0-1-tissot.img
```

In TWRP I launched command line and with a single command

```
resize2fs /dev/block/mmcblk0p49 <newsize>
```

the problem was solved. I did not extend to the full size of the partition but left some MBs (at the end) because I seem to remember having read that this space is necessary for meta data when encrypting the device.